# How to access the indices of the elements in a array that matches the condition

Tags: ruby

I'm new to ruby and trying to solve this problem. I want to list the indices in array that matches the condition

```
array[any] + array[any] == X
```

ex:

```
array = [5, 6, 15, 20]

X = 11
```

Now index 0 and 1 match the condition, with the below code

```
array.combination(2).to_a { |a,b| a+b == 11 }
```

How do I print the indices that matched the condition. 
Expected output : `[0,1]`

```
def indices(array, X)
  array.combination(2).to_a { |a,b| a+b == X }
end
```

Expected output : `[0,1]`

Answer (score 5):

```
array = [4, 6, 5, 3, 20, 7]
x = 10

arr = array.each_index.
            to_a.
            combination(2).
            select { |i,j| i != j && array[i] + array[j] == x }
  #=> [[0, 1], [3, 5]] 

 p arr
 [[0, 1], [3, 5]]
```

Without `i != j` `[2, 2]` would be included in the return value.

Answer (score 1):

it'll done the trick for you..try it out

```
array.combination(2).to_a.map{ |x| d = x  if x.sum == 11}.reject{|x| x==nil}.flatten.map{|y| array.index(y)}
```

Comment: This works in most of the cases, however failing when the array has only 2 elements. Example: array = [3,3] and x = 6. outputs [0,0]

Answer (score 0):

You can scan each element against the rest of the array, looking for the matches in a nested loop, without Array#combination:

```
array = [1, 4, 5, 6, 9, 15, 20]
x = 10

array.flat_map.with_index { |a, i| array[i+1..].map.with_index { |b, j| [i, j + i + 1] if a + b == x }.compact }
#=> [[0, 4], [1, 3]]
```

Also similar but without Array#compact:

```
array.flat_map.with_index { |a, i| array[i+1..].each_with_index.with_object([]) { |(b, j), o| o << [i, j + i + 1] if a + b == x } }
```

---

Or yet another couple of option using [Array#combination](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.4/Array.html#method-i-combination):

```
array.zip(0..).combination(2).select { |(a, i), (b, j)| a + b == x }.map(&:to_h).map(&:values)

array.zip(0..).combination(2).map { |(a, i), (b, j)| [i, j] if a + b == x }.compact
```